# Visit girlfriend (non US citizen) on ESTA

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, esta

I know there are a lot of questions about this but my case is a little different from the others.
I’m Alessandro, 22, from Italy. I started texting with a girl from my city a couple of months ago and we took this thing seriously. She is in the US with a J1 visa and being an au pair girl she lives with their host parents and kids etc... Now, she talked with them and they are happy to have me with them. 
So I will spend two weeks there, we will also travel to Toronto for St. Valentine’s day weekend. 
I am a little worried about CBP clearence.
Could I be denied enter US with these conditions? Also:
-Traveled on ESTA 2 times in last 5 years (2 weeks max)
-Bringing a promise ring in my carry on bag 
-300$ cash and 200€ cash plus cards
If asked what’s the purpose of my trip I’m not going to hide anything and I’ll say “I’m visiting my girlfriend. She’s Italian and she’s here for a while”
I appreciate any suggestion and happy to hear your opinion.

Thank you so much.
Alessandro.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visiting girlfriend in the USA](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144942/visiting-girlfriend-in-the-usa)

Comment: There's really nothing unusual about your situation. Be prepared to show that you have available funds and that you'll leave after your visit and you should be fine.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass The questions are a little different because in this one the girlfriend is on a limited duration visa and expected to return to their common home country.

Comment: Exactly @Patricia. Both me and my gf have all relatives in Italy and she is coming back. I’m only spending 2 weeks with her. I can proof this if asked by a looot of old WhatsApp messages. We know each other for a short period of time and she is on a J1 visa so I think this would work in my favour.

Comment: BTW thank you @Arthur’sPass. Other then messages etc. I can show, if asked, a picture of my last paycheck i.e.